# vscode debug deno script stops a decode.json.dew.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, deno

I got debugging with deno working in vscode

> .vscode/launch.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Deno",
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "-A", "--allow-net", "adBlockFinder.1m.ts"],
      "attachSimplePort": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

But it always starts out by breaking in some other file called `decode.json.dew.js` (not created by me)

[image: the file that i breaks in]

"Playing the debug" (pressing the play looking icon) gets to the next breakpoint set by me.

Does anybody know how to avoid having to press "debug play" every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think this is expected behavior for now when using `--inspect-brk` (vs. `--inspect`). From section 2.7 in the manual, [*Debugging your code*](https://deno.land/manual@v1.13.0/getting_started/debugging_your_code):

> You might notice that DevTools pauses execution on the first line of `_constants.ts` instead of `file_server.ts`. This is expected behavior caused by the way ES modules are evaluated in JavaScript (`_constants.ts` is left-most, bottom-most dependency of `file_server.ts` so it is evaluated first).